# PHP RegEx in textarea

Tags: php, regex, textarea

I have this warning appearing where I have a reg expression check in a textarea.

Warning: ereg(): REG_BADBR in contact/library.php

My code is

```
function validateMessage($message) {
    if(ereg('^[A-Za-z0-9[:punct:]]{2,300}$',$message)){
            return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is it receiving the error because i have the wrong ereg or because it is in a textarea?!

Comment: It's better to provide comments, not only code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ereg` is deprecated, use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead:

```
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9[:punct:]]{2,300}$/',$message)){
```